# How to convert Func<Vector<double>, double> to Func<double[], double>

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, type-conversion

I am trying to convert `Func<MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector<double>, double>` to `Func<double[], double>`, but couldn't find a way.

The reason I need to do is: I get an argument in the first form and I have to pass it in the second form. Basically, I have to map each double value in a Vector to a double value in a double array.

Is there a way to do this conversion, perhaps with reflection?

EDIT:

`Vector<T>` is abstract.

`DenseVector<T>` is one of the classes that implements `Vector<T>`

Example vector initialization with `double[]`:

```
new DenseVector(new double [] { });
```

Comment: How do you create a [`MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector<double>`](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra/Vector%601.htm) from a `double[]` with acceptable runtime performance (whatever that is)? I don't see any constructors in the documentation; seems like that's a base class or something?

Comment: @EdPlunkett See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, DenseVector is just what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is huge and creating a `Vector` from it is expensive, this may not be a good solution, but it'll be easy enough to find that out.

It may be preferable simply to rewrite a big chunk of your `double[]` code with `Vector<double>`, to avoid converting back and forth all the time. I don't know enough about your code to say which solution is preferable, but if all this messing around with constructors brings your code to its knees, that approach is a good bet.

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;

// ...stuff...

Func<Vector<double>, double> fv /*coming from somewhere */;

Func<double[], double> fa = (ary) => fv(new DenseVector<double>(ary));
```

There's not much future in casting one lambda type to another, but you can always have one *call* another with appropriate conversion or casting code.

If you need to "convert" an array of `Vector<double>` lambdas likewise, this should work:

```
Func<Vector<double>, double>[] fva /*coming from somewhere */;

Func<double[], double>[] fda = 
    fva.Select(fv => 
        new Func<double[], double>>(ary => fv(new DenseVector<double>(ary))
    ).ToArray();
```

Or to spare my poor aching mind parser:

```
public Func<T[], T> ConvertVectorToArrayFunc<T>(Func<Vector<T>, T> f)
    => a => f(new DenseVector<T>(a));

// ... snip ...

    Func<double[], double> fa = ConvertVectorToArrayFunc(fv);

    Func<double[], double>[] fda =
        fva.Select(ConvertVectorToArrayFunc).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, what if we need to convert arrays of them, ie: `Func<Vector<double>, double>[]`  to `Func<double[], double>[]`